# Delete User session of Azure ADB2C using MSAL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application, azure-ad-b2c

I have integrated Azure ADB2C in React SPA, using MSAL package. Both login and logout is working fine. My requirement is, After user successfully changes the password in Azure ADB2C update password page I am redirecting user to confirmation page stating that they have successfully changed the password and displayed a "Continue" button on click of that, the user will be made to signed out of the application.

The above scenario works fine, but if the user without clicking the "Continue" button, clicks on the browser back button, the user can visit the authenticated pages and the user is still authorized to visit the pages. But instead I want the user to get logged off from the application.

Is there any way in Azure ADB2C to delete the active user session alternatively without triggering the button.

While clicking on the button am calling Signout policy already defined.